# vm workstation is having virtual machine but how to communicate vm to windows pc different ip address

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, bridged

in windows7 having vmware workstation 10 and created one centos vm is having start with 10.10.10.2 series ip address and window7 having with 192.168.1.28 series ip address but vm to windows pc how to communicate?

Comment: virtual machine to windows pc how will be communicate through ip address's series is different

Comment: You are asking to go from a different subnet. This is only possible if NAT is involved. Or some form of vlan trunking.

Comment: yes this is different ip address series and different submask  ............            i want to be communicate virtual machine ip address to be ping on windows pc how can possiable plz help to me (using only "bridged" option)

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of things to try (assuming the Widows 7 machine you speak of is your host machine).

1. Use the [VMware network editor to setup a new "Host Only" virtual network](http://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-10/index.jsp#com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-2DE2FC75-BDDE-4817-A93D-A2766D9159F8.html?resultof=%2522%256e%2565%2574%2577%256f%2572%256b%2522%2520%2522%2565%2564%2569%2574%256f%2572%2522%2520) with a 10.10.10.x subnet/IP and configure the host machine to have a virtual NIC in that network as well.
2. If you just want to access files on your host machine then you could always just use the "[Shared Folders](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/running_sharefold_ws.html)" or Host Guest File System (HGFS) feature.  Once configured, shared folders can be viewed in the guest OS under `/mnt/hgfs`.